# Why winApi request a file handle and say "The file will be opened"

Tags: winapi, iis

The documentation for the [`HSE_TF_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524981.aspx) structure states:

> **hFile**
>
> Handle to the file to be opened. The file will be opened using the
>   Win32 CreateFile function with the FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN and
>   FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED values turned on.

I don't understand this. If I need to give a file handle, then I must already do `CreateFile(...)` to retrieve this handle (how else can I find the handle?), so why are they asking for a handle and say that "The file **will be opened** ..."?

Comment: only bad documentation. you open this `hFile` yourself

Comment: thanks @rbMm yes look like strange, however opening the file with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED  or not change nothing it's seam ...

Comment: information from `HSE_TF_INFO` used to call `TransmitFile`, which internally call `MSAFD_TransmitFile` - `ZwDeviceIoControlFile` - all next already will be done in kernel.  using `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` and `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` can improve performance , but you not view difference in functional

Comment: thanks RbMn i will stay like this !